# Pass string as argument into C program in terminal

Tags: c, linux

So i'm working on linux and my question is how make a program accept arguments in execution like this one:

./program am i

Also both functions work the same way at the moment, because i'm struggling  with getting only this line:
(expected result of show_info_who_am_i)

Kamil    pts/0    2015-11-12 10:14 (:0)

instead of both of them:
(result of show_info_who)

Kamil    tty2     2015-11-12 10:13 (:0)

Kamil    pts/0    2015-11-12 10:14 (:0)

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <utmp.h>
#include    <fcntl.h>
#include    <unistd.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <time.h>
#include    <sys/types.h>

#define SHOWHOST    /* include remote machine on output */

show_info_who( struct utmp *utbufp )
{
    if(utbufp->ut_type > 4){
        time_t czas = utbufp->ut_time;
        char buf[80];
        struct tm* timeinfo = localtime(&czas);

        printf("%-8.8s", utbufp->ut_name);  /* the logname  */
        printf(" ");                /* a space  */
        printf("%-8.8s", utbufp->ut_line);  /* the tty  */
        printf(" ");                /* a space  */
        strftime(buf, 80, "%F %R" , timeinfo);
        printf("%s", buf);
        printf(" ");                /* a space  */


    #ifdef  SHOWHOST
        printf("(%s)", utbufp->ut_host);    /* the host */
    #endif
        printf("\n");               /* newline  */
    }
}

show_info_who_am_i( struct utmp *utbufp )
{
    if(utbufp->ut_type > 4){
        time_t czas = utbufp->ut_time;
        char buf[80];
        struct tm* timeinfo = localtime(&czas);

        printf("%-8.8s", utbufp->ut_name);  /* the logname  */
        printf(" ");                /* a space  */
        printf("%-8.8s", utbufp->ut_line);  /* the tty  */
        printf(" ");                /* a space  */
        strftime(buf, 80, "%F %R" , timeinfo);
        printf("%s", buf);
        printf(" ");                /* a space  */


    #ifdef  SHOWHOST
        printf("(%s)", utbufp->ut_host);    /* the host */
    #endif
        printf("\n");               /* newline  */
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct utmp current_record; /* read info into here       */
    int     utmpfd;     /* read from this descriptor */
    int     reclen = sizeof(current_record);

    if ( (utmpfd = open(UTMP_FILE, O_RDONLY)) == -1 ){
        perror( UTMP_FILE );    /* UTMP_FILE is in utmp.h    */
        exit(1);
    }

    //char am[22] = "am";    /* test */
    //char i[22] = "i";    /* test */

    //printf("%s,%s\n\n", am,i);    /* test */
    //printf("%s", argv[1]);

    if(argv[1]== "am"){
        if(argv[2]== "i"){
            while ( read(utmpfd, &current_record, reclen) == reclen )
                show_info_who_am_i(&current_record);
        }
    }
    else{
        while ( read(utmpfd, &current_record, reclen) == reclen )
            show_info_who(&current_record);         
    }
    //printf("%s,%s", argv[1], argv[2]);      /* test */
    close(utmpfd);
    return 0;           /* went ok */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! @user3121023

Comment: check `argc` before trying to access `argv`